# Passing max to pandas df with agg yields arbitrary result

Tags: python, pandas

I believe the source of my problem may be a datatype problem, but when I attempted to convert to integer type, the problem was not resolved.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dogs':['1', '3', '7', '10', '-3'], 'Cats':['5', '12', '13', '23', '-13']})
MaxDogs = df.agg({'Dogs':'max', 'Cats':'max'})
print(MaxDogs)

Dogs    7
Cats    5
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is causing by you did not assign it back ,if we only display the result we can chain `agg`

```
MaxDogs = df.astype(int).agg({'Dogs':'max', 'Cats':'max'})
MaxDogs

Dogs    10
Cats    23
dtype: int64
```